# Why .enableSassLoader() webpack encore doen't work with new symfony5 project

Tags: webpack, symfony5

After installing new symfony5 project with Webpack encore installed and .enableSassLoader() activated in webpack.config.js when running `yarn encore dev` I have got the following error message :

```
............webpack.config.js:57

 .enableSassLoader()
 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
.........
.....
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have the same webpack.config.js configuration in another symfony4 project directory in the same Linux ubuntu computer and it works perfectly!

What's wrong?

Comment: are you sure that these webpack.config.js are perfectly the same?
Can you show webpack.config.js file content?

Comment: You might want to reset to default your webpack.condig.js 
Are you sure you .enableSassLoader() is properly placed under the Encore tag?
or there is another typo showing in the file?